# Sending a file from angular to web api as a property

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular8, webapi

In angular model

```
MyClass.ts
  name: string
  age: number
  file: File
```

In web api
Save(MyClassDto)

MyClassDto.cs

```
 string name;
 int age;
 IFormFile file;
```

On button click from UI:

MyClass is passed with

```
name='test'
age=10,
file=document.getElementById('fileElement').files[0]; -> for ex:'C:\fakepath\testfile.jpg"
```

When the web api is called, i get this error:

api - post method that passes dto object as a parameter.

Save(MyClassDto myClassDto);

> IFormFile Deserialization of interface types is not supported error.

Any idea how to send file when IFormFile is a property in both the models?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class that IMPLEMENTS the IFormFile interface in the web API. Interfaces are not meant to be instantiated, so it cannot be deserialized in the webapi code.

Then you should change the parameter signature of the web api myclassDto into:

```
string name;
 int age;
 NewFormFileClassThatImplementsTheIFormFile file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems, i need to use FormData, there is no object mapping easily.

```
const formData=new FormData();
formData.append('name', 'test name');
formData.append('file', file);
save(formData);
```

Then, the api receives both model and file.

Also, don't forget to add [FromForm] inside the post api method

> Save([FromForm] MyClassDto myClassDto);